# Jack's Leadership and Nisha Blood of the Guilty

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I'm playing with another person and I'm wondering if this combination of skill works (we're too low level to try):

- Jack with Leadership (every digi-jack death counts as a kill)
- Nisha with Blood of the guilty (every kill from herself or an ally
  will recover health and generate order stacks)

Will digi-jacks dying with leadership proc Nisha's blood of the guilty?

Answer (score 1):

I reached a level high enough to try it myself.

It looks like digi-jack leadership "kills" don't count as actual kills, and they only work towards activating jack's kill skills.

This means that skills activating with the condition "allied kill", such as Nisha's Blood of the Guilty, don't proc off of digi-jacks' death.